# Is a mouse click on a remote desktop possible using AutoIt or alternatives?

Tags: windows, automation, autoit

I want to write a script that involves mouse click and stuff. I am little confused though. Is there a way mouse clicks (in the form of x and y co-ordinates) would work on a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) which is logged on, but disconnected from the client?

Example:

```
MouseClick("left",588, 268)
```

To my knowledge, these VPSes don't have their own native screen resolution. I have already written the script for my local pc and it's working fine on my resolution. But when tried with the VPS, it doesn't work.

PS: I am running the script from the remote desktop itself and not from my local pc. Please correct me if there's anything I am doing wrong :)

Update: For anyone still looking for an answer, consider installing a vnc server, that way the screen resolution you specify is preserved even when not connected to the server. 
Ex: https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/

Comment: MouseClick("left",588, 268) will work different on different resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relevant to almost any automation tool, not only AutoIt.

Remote Desktop has its own GUI context only if it's connected to the remote PC. But you can lose focus for a Remote Desktop window (without disconnection & without minimizing) and continue other local work.

The same effect takes place for [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) server software.

One team in our organization uses it for massive test runs automation: a master server creates a remote session for each test machine and keeps them all connected until tests passes.

Comment: So its been a while, but I just wanted to say that I solved this problem sometime ago by running tightvnc on the server, and modifying its setting to "Do Nothing", when the last user disconnects. This makes the server retain its GUI Context ( You can set the resolution just like you could on a normal computer ). And then I can run AutoIt with ControlClick or even Click using the X,Y co ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ControlClick` to have the mouse click over RDP connections, even when you're not connected. For some reason it can still be iffy for me, but at least it worked more so that `Click` which was none at all.